# Using Glimpse on a javascript website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, node.js, angularjs, glimpse

I have a website that is written with Node.js/AngularJS that makes ajax calls to an ASP.Net mvc backend. Because I don't use the traditional 'Views' and 'aspx' pages, is there a way to use Glimpse in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, this is something we need to support better.

What you could do as a workaround is create one "standard" MVC view used just to serve HTML and the Glimpse client.

After that press the "pop out" button in Glimpse to open it in a new window, and then use the history tab to select requests to inspect.

Eventually we'd like to have a stand alone Glimpse client so that you wouldn't have to jump through this hoop - but we aren't there yet